# Common Lisp equality on symbol in web application

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, equality, symbols, hunchentoot

The following function:

```
(defun check-for-arrow (x)
  (format t "**~s**~s**~s**~s**"
          (length (string x))
          x
          (eq x '->)
          (and (eq (elt (string x) 0) #\-)
               (eq (elt (string x) 1) #\>))) ; for debug
  (eq x '->))
```

when called from REPL, with:

```
(check-for-arrow '->)
```

prints, with tracing:

```
0> Calling (CHECK-FOR-ARROW ->) 
**2**->**T**T**
<0 CHECK-FOR-ARROW returned T
```

Instead, when called inside a Hunchentoot web application, over data read in a form, when called over the symbol '->', prints:

```
0> Calling (NORMALIZER::CHECK-FOR-ARROW ->) 
**2**->**NIL**T**
<0 NORMALIZER::CHECK-FOR-ARROW returned NIL
```

The Lisp is Clozure Common Lisp.

Does this depend on a different way of interning symbols ? It is possible to use 'eq' on symbols or I have to transform the arrow in a string and check for string equality?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: something like `->` is a symbol and an atom. The word atom has a different meaning from just symbol. Everything which is not a cons cell is an atom. Thus the number `3`, the string `"foo"`, the vector `#(1 2 3)`, ... are all atoms - but they are not symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp has packages. Packages are kind of namespaces for symbols.

Thus one can have many different symbols named "->", each one in a different package.

Thus `normalizer::->` is not necessarily `EQ` to `cl-user::->`.

Symbols can also be NOT interned in a package, thus one can have many different symbols of the same name and no a package.

```
CL-USER 2 > '#:->
#:->

CL-USER 3 > (describe *)

#:-> is a SYMBOL
NAME          "->"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       NIL

CL-USER 4 > '->
->

CL-USER 5 > (describe *)

-> is a SYMBOL
NAME          "->"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
```

A typical problem:

One has a function which tests for EQ of something with a certain symbol `FOO`. The user inputs `FOO`.

But how does your Lisp function convert the user input into a symbol? In which package will the symbol be? Remember symbols differ by name AND package. If you don't specify the package, the default is the value of the variable `CL:*PACKAGE*`. But this variable can have different values at different times.

Just extend your test function to print the packages of the symbols and you will see the difference.

```
CL-USER 7 > (package-name (symbol-package '->))
"COMMON-LISP-USER"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I needed this clarification! I can see that the package of '-> for the web application is "COMMON-LISP-USER", while for '-> written in the function it is "NORMALIZER". And, by the way, there is a simple way of checking only the "name" part of the symbol?

Comment: Answering to my previous question, I suppose that the "best" way of performing this test is with: `(string= (symbol-name x) (symbol-name '->))`.

Comment: @renzo: a shorter function than `symbol-name` is `string`.

Comment: @renzo: string= happens to be willing to compare symbol names directly if you want (it takes "string designators" which include symbols). I think I would be most inclined to bind \*package\* around the reading of the second symbol and use eq if that's a convenient thing to do in the code.